# Fresh install of 12.04 on release

Tags: 11.10, installation, 12.04

My current version of 11.10 is plagued with shutdown/reboot bugs that are basically unfixable because of something I did months ago. Coupled with totem errors, malfunctioning recent files... etc.

When 12.04 comes out at the end of April, I have decided to stick with Ubuntu instead of switching to Mac. My filesystem has the following on different partitions:

```
/
(swap)
/home
/home/Videos
/home/Television
```

When I burn and run the install disc of 12.04, do I just pick the previous partions out in the advanced mode and then choose to reformat root `/` to perform a clean install? I don't care about the application packages I lose, I can easily download them again.

Comment: A lot of the user configuration files are in /home. I would think seriously about backing up your data and emails and browser bookmarks and re-formatting /home and then migrate everything back afterwards. Start off with clean configuration files. Otherwise you might still get conflicts from old configuration settings. This is what am going to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your plan should work just fine. With that said, I would still advise backups ;)